# Sqoop & Hadoop - How to join/merge old data and new data imported by Sqoop in lastmodified mode?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, merge, hive, sqoop

**Background:**

I have a table with the following schema on a SQL server. Updates to existing rows is possible and new rows are also added to this table.

```
unique_id | user_id | last_login_date       | count
123-111   |   111   | 2016-06-18 19:07:00.0 | 180
124-100   |   100   | 2016-06-02 10:27:00.0 | 50
```

I am using Sqoop to add incremental updates in lastmodified mode. My --check-column parameter is the last_login_date column. In my **first run**, I got the above two records into Hadoop - let's call this current data. I noted that the last value (the max value of the the check column from this first import) is 2016-06-18 19:07:00.0.

Assuming there is a change on the SQL server side, I now have the following changes on the SQL server side:

```
unique_id | user_id | last_login_date       | count
123-111   |   111   | 2016-06-25 20:10:00.0 | 200
124-100   |   100   | 2016-06-02 10:27:00.0 | 50
125-500   |   500   | 2016-06-28 19:54:00.0 | 1
```

I have the row 123-111 updated with a more recent last_login_date value and the count column has also been updated. I also have a new row 125-500 added.

On my **second** run, sqoop looks at all columns with a last_login_date column greater than my known last value from the previous import - 2016-06-18 19:07:00.0

This gives me only the **changed data**, i.e. 123-111 and 125-500 records. Let's call this - new data.

**Question**

How do I do a merge join in Hadoop/Hive using the current data and the new data so that I end up with the updated version of 123-111, 124-100, and the newly added 125-500?

Answer (score 1):

Changed data load using scoop is a two phase process.

1. 1st phase - load changed data into some temp (stage) table using
   sqoop import utility.
2. 2nd phase - Merge changed data with old data using sqoop-merge
   utility.

If the table is small(say few M records) then use full load using sqoop import.

Sometimes it's possible to load only latest partition - in such case use sqoop import utility to load partition using custom query, then instead of merge simply insert overwrite loaded partition into target table, or copy files - this will work faster than sqoop merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the existing Sqoop **query** (by specifying a new custom query) to get **ALL the data** from the source table instead of getting only the **changed data**. Refer [using_sqoop_to_move_data_into_hive](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_dataintegration/content/using_sqoop_to_move_data_into_hive.html). This would be the simplest way to accomplish this - i.e doing a full data refresh instead of applying deltas.